# Install/Upgrade rpm based on the version mentioned in a list

Tags: bash, shell, installation, upgrade, rpm

I'm maintaining a list of rpm and it's version that needs to be installed

sample packages list below

```
#                  Package          Version              Release                                                     Filename
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               mongo-10gen            2.2.0      mongodb_1.x86_64                       mongo-10gen-2.2.0-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm
        mongo-10gen-server            2.2.0      mongodb_1.x86_64                mongo-10gen-server-2.2.0-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm
                      cpio             2.10       11.el6_3.x86_64                                cpio-2.10-11.el6_3.x86_64.rpm
```

And I'm checking whether the package is already installed and if it's of lower version update rpm or if it's not available install it.

```
pkg=($@)
vinfo=($(rpm -q --qf "%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH} " ${pkg[0]} 2>&1))
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    need_upgrade=1
    for vrs in ${vinfo[@]}
    do
        if [[ "${pkg[1]}-${pkg[2]}" = "$vrs" ]]
        then
            need_upgrade=0
        elif [[ "${pkg[1]}-${pkg[2]}" < "$vrs" ]]
        then
            need_upgrade=0
        fi
    done
    if [ $need_upgrade -eq 1 ]
    then
        rpm -Uvh "$PKG_DIR/${pkg[3]}" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
        rc=$?
    fi
else
    rpm -ivh "$PKG_DIR/${pkg[3]}" >> $LOGFILE 2>&1
    rc=$?
fi
```

But the string comparison with `<` is comparing the strings lexicographically hence it's not working the way that I expect. In some cases, e.g. here exists a cpio of version `2.10-9.el6.x86_64`. When it compares whether `"2.10-11.el6_3.x86_64" < "2.10-9.el6.x86_64"` the `elif` condition returns true hence it's not upgrading the packages.

Is there any other good approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort -VC`, from man sort :

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text

   -C, --check=quiet, --check=silent
          like -c, but do not report first bad line
```

maybe

```
if sort -VC <<END
${pkg[1]}-${pkg[2]}
$vrs
END
  then
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** can be used to split out the 11 and 9 part from the input and then making comparisons.

This is the sample script:

```
version=`echo "2.10-11.el6_3.x86_64" |  awk -F'.' '{print $2}' | awk -F'-' '{print 
$2}'`

versiontocompare=`echo "2.10-9.el6_3.x86_64" |  awk -F'.' '{print $2}' | awk -F'-' 
'{print $2}'`

# version contains 11 now and versiontocompare contains 9
echo "$version $versiontocompare"

if [ $version -gt $versiontocompare ]
then
  echo "Ok $version is greater than $versiontocompare. Do update"
else
 echo "Do not update"
fi
```